# How to find out if an installed Erlang is 32 or 64 bit version?

Tags: erlang, 32bit-64bit

I have installed Erlang from source by `./configure --enable-m32-build --prefix=/usr/local/erlang`

and when run `erl` :

```
Erlang R15B03 (erts-5.9.3.1) [source] [64-bit] [smp:4:4] [async-threads:0] [hipe] [kernel-poll:false] [dtrace]

Eshell V5.9.3.1  (abort with ^G)
```

Does it mean the erlang version is 64 bit ? In order to run Ejabberd,  I want to install 32 bit erlang on my Lion(64 bit OS)

Answer (score 3):

It is a 64 bit build. You may want to check out the --enable-halfword-emulator flag which has most of the 32bit advantages on a 64bit machine.

Comment: halfword seems not that well supported. I had a research project written in Erlang for some simulation. Using halfword it crashes around 6GB while 64bit without halfword runs smoothly to even 30GB.

Comment: Halfword is supposed to be fully supported, so you should definitely report that bug.

Comment: OK thanks, I will try to simplify my settings and report a bug then. :-)